# Value not printing(java)?

Tags: java, return

I have the following code executed and when I try to print it out no value besides 0.0 prints:

```
public class RegularPolygon {
 private int numSides; //# sides
 private double sideLength; //side length 
 private double inscribedRadius; //radius of inscribed circle

 private void calcr(){
    inscribedRadius = .5 * sideLength * 1/Math.tan(Math.PI / numSides);
  }
}

public double getr(){
   return inscribedRadius;
}
```

Main:

```
RegularPolygon poly = new RegularPolygon(4, 10);
System.out.println(poly.getr());
```

Output:

```
0.0
```

Constructor:

```
    public RegularPolygon(int newNumSides, double newSideLength){
    numSides = newNumSides;
    sideLength = newSideLength;
}
```

What is preventing it from printing out?

Comment: Where's your constructor? You didn't call `caclr()`.

Comment: where is your regularpolygon constructor

Comment: you have asked 17 questions till date but you haven't accepted answer for any of the question. It is best practice to accept the answer as it encourages the users and SO runs that way only. If you are benefited from anyone answer simply accept it buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Since your constructor doesn't initialize `inscribedRadius` and you haven't called `calcr()`, the value of `inscribedRadius` remains 0, which is the default value assigned to primitive fields during instance initialization.

```
RegularPolygon poly = new RegularPolygon(4, 10);
poly.calcr();
System.out.println(poly.getr());
```

This is only possible if the above code is executed in your `RegularPolygon` class. Because your method is `private` it is not visible outside that class. In that case, you would need to setup your design so as to call `calcr()` internally.

Comment: But `calcr()` is private. Would be better of calling in Constructor.

Comment: @Java Thank you, missed that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Just edit your getr() function. You have to call calcr() function 

public double getr(){
    calcr();
    return inscribedRadius;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your RegularPolygon class

```
public RegularPolygon(int numSides, double sideLength){
this.numSides=numSides;
this.sideLength=sideLength;

}
```

Then call the `calcr();`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a *constructor* to set the values of the fields you've defined, then invoke your `calcr()` function in it, to calculate the value for `inscribedRadius`.  Also, getr() should probably be moved inside the `RegularPolygon` class.

For example:

```
public class RegularPolygon {
  private int numSides; //# sides
  private double sideLength; //side length 
  private double inscribedRadius; //radius of inscribed circle

  public RegularPolygon(int numSides, double sideLength) {
    this.numSides = numSides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
    this.calcr();
  }

  private void calcr(){
    inscribedRadius = .5 * sideLength * 1/Math.tan(Math.PI / numSides);
  }

  public double getr(){
    return inscribedRadius;
  }
}
```

See http://ideone.com/lxcmlH for a running example of this code.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer.  You're also not calling `calcr()` to get the value for `inscribedRadius`.

Comment: At least not in your OP.  The `RegularPolygon` class ends with the curly brace after the end of `calcr()`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your constructor to calculate the radius

```
public RegularPolygon(int newNumSides, double newSideLength){
     numSides = newNumSides;
     sideLength = newSideLength;
     this.calcr();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When class RegularPolygon is been instanced, because you don't give a initialized value to field inscribedRadius, its field inscribedRadius will be initialized as 0.0. Before you call poly.getr(), you don't do anything, so printing out can only be 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added constructor to your class?

If not add

```
public RegularPolygon(int numSides, double sideLength){
this.numSides=numSides;
this.sideLength=sideLength;

}
```

and then call

```
poly.calcr();
```

before printing the value.

You are getting 0.0 because you havn't initalized varalble and also you havn't called method to calculate `inscribedRadius`.

If you havn't initialized any int or double variable, the default initilization will be 0. Thats why you getting `0.0`.